# How to include project path in website using WAMP Server

Tags: php, wamp

I am trying to setup set up local website in my wampserver.

However, I am facing an issue which I need help with.

I am getting error when trying to access another page from index.php.

> 'Warning: include(localhost/main_project/includes/contants.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\main_project\index.php on line 55'.

However, I see my file, constants.php, in the includes folder. This is how I set up my path in index.php

```
$project_path = 'localhost/main_project/';
```

I use this variable to go to refer to constants.php

```
include $project_path . 'includes/constants.php';
```

Please let me know what I should be doing.

Thank you!

Comment: `localhost` is in your URL, but it seems you have not any directory named localhost.You are already in `main_project` so use `./includes/constants.php` or even `__DIR__.'/includes/constants.php'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do what you're trying to accomplish. The path specified in `include` and `require` can only be a relative path. If you want to add a base variable to it you could do:

```
$relativePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include $relativePath.'/includes/contants.php';
```

Comment: Sorry I meant 'include $project_path . 'includes/constants.php'; I will edit my post.

Comment: don't use the `$project_path`

Comment: Yes...if I do not use project_path and directly include 'includes/constants.php';, then it works fine. But I have nested folders from which I need to use project-path to point to other files. And I am trying to use project_path as a starting point to be consistent from all the pages in many levels.